# $k$-flat in $n$-space, leading zero columns

Tags: matrices

I understand that the solution space of the augmented matrix $AM =$
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right]
$$
is considered to be a "$1$-flat" in $3$-space, because there is one "free" variable, but what if I have
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
as my matrix in $4$-space? Would it be called a "$2$-flat", because there are two independent variables? Is there any nomenclature distinction between the variables $w$ and $z$ in the variables vector $X =$ 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
w \\
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $AX = B$, $B =$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2
\end{bmatrix} \text{ ?}
$$

The $w$ and $z$ variables are both independent, but $x$ and $y$ are only dependent on $z$, not $w$.

Comment: I changed $\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & | & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & | & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ to $\displaystyle \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \end{array}\right].$  ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a $2$-flat -- you're correct.  And I don't know of any nomenclature distinction between free variables that other variables depend on and ones that other variables don't depend on.  Both are just free (or independent) variables.

Comment: OK, thank you. It seems like examples including variables independent like 'w' are not part of my course, but they turned up in a problem.